# C# connect to URL via proxy fails

Tags: c#, proxy

This is my code. What am i trying to do is connect to webservice and download a file to a specific location.

Code throws an exception. Looks like i should retun some value to service before i download a file (not sure tho).

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
NetworkCredential netCred=new NetworkCredential();
netCred.UserName="user";
netCred.Password="pass";
netCred.Domain="domain";
webClient.Credentials = netCred;
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy();
wp.Credentials = netCred;
wp.Address = new Uri(@"http://okolje.arso.gov.si/service/prevozniki.zip");
webClient.Proxy = wp;
webClient.DownloadFile("http://okolje.arso.gov.si/service/prevozniki.zip", @"C:\arso\prevozniki.zip");
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - can you clarify? What is the exception thrown? What do you want to do when you encounter the exception?

Comment: You're not setting the proxy address correctly: [`WebProxy.Address`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.address.aspx): _"Gets or sets the address of the proxy server"_.

Comment: i dont see the proxy address? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10779198/2027232

Comment: thank you. My obvious mistake. Works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to say what port your proxy is e.g.

```
webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8118");
```

you also have to actually set up this proxy, webclient.proxy just uses it, it doesn't create it

I'm not entirely sure what the rest of your code is doing, but I don't think you need the

```
wp.Address = new Uri(@"http://okolje.arso.gov.si/service/prevozniki.zip");
```

Comment: exaclty what i was missing!