# WebClient: Credentials + Proxy: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, proxy, webclient

The following is being tested on Windows 8 and 7.

I have this code, which works when not behind a proxy:

```
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(USER, PASS);

        client.DownloadFile("http://mydns/subfolder/myfile.zip")
```

The client USER and PASS is a local user on the server.

When I combine that with a proxy, I keep getting the 401 error:

```
            var proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            client.Proxy = proxy;
```

The client has the correct proxy configured, because with the browser I can go to the wanted url.
I also tried with manually setting the proxy Credentials, but that also didn't work:

```
            WebProxy proxy;

            if(_proxySetting.Port != null)
                proxy = new WebProxy(_proxySetting.Server, _proxySetting.Port);
            else
                proxy = new WebProxy(_proxySetting.Server);

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_proxySetting.Username))
            {
                proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_proxySetting.Username, _proxySetting.Password);
            }

            client.Proxy = proxy;
```

I've tried what is explained on the following pages, without any luck:

[WebClient generates (401) Unauthorized error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150161/webclient-generates-401-unauthorized-error)

[C# webclient and proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817548/c-sharp-webclient-and-proxy-server)

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?517076-RESOLVED-2005-WebClient-Credentials-allways-getting-401!

Any help is much appreciated since I'm totally out of ideas.