# 403 Forbidden with WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient

The company I work for have a limited internet connection and we use the proxy (example: 10.10.10.10:8080) to access at some restricted connections.

I can use the API in Postman (putting the proxy in the Postman settings) but when putting in the C# WebClient code it gives me a 403-Forbidden error.

I only need the `var sensorData` field but I splitted in `var data` and `var data2` to understand where was the problem. It gives me the error at the `var data = ...`

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://XXXXXXXX/api/DatasourceData/DatasourceDataHistoryBySerialNumber/");
Token token = new Token();
token = GetToken(tokenAPI);

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  try
  {
    client.Proxy = new WebProxy("10.10.10.10", 8080);
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.AccessToken);
    client.QueryString.Add("serialNumbersDatasource", "I2001258");
    client.QueryString.Add("startDate", string.Format("{0:s}", "2019-12-01"));
    client.QueryString.Add("endDate", string.Format("{0:s}", DateTime.Now));
    client.QueryString.Add("isFilterDatesByDataDate", "false");

    var data = client.DownloadData(uri);
    var data2 = (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));

    sensorData = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sensor>>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.DownloadData(uri))))[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems the problem at this line

```
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "tokenTest");
```

here you wil add header `Authorization` with value `Bearer tokenTest`

so, 403 Forbidden returns by service which you are addressing, but not a proxy

change to

```
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenTest);
```

and check if `tokenTest` has valid value

Comment: That's what I had, I changed for better understanding that I was passing a string. I edited the code to be similar to what I have

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you need any additional properties on the proxy. You may possibly need to enable:

> UseDefaultCredentials (Boolean) true if the default credentials are
>   used; otherwise, false. The default value is false

Also, check your full url and query string that you are producing - look at the outgoing request fabricated (in the debugger) or through [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and make sure it all lines up, url, query string, headers, etc.

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy?view=netframework-4.8):

**Address** 
Gets or sets the address of the proxy server.

**BypassArrayList** 
Gets a list of addresses that do not use the proxy server.

**BypassList**
Gets or sets an array of addresses that do not use the proxy server.

**BypassProxyOnLocal**
Gets or sets a value that indicates whether to bypass the proxy server for local addresses.

**Credentials** 
Gets or sets the credentials to submit to the proxy server for authentication.

**UseDefaultCredentials**
Gets or sets a Boolean value that controls whether the DefaultCredentials are sent with requests.

Comment: UseDefaultCredentials at true or false gives the same output, error 403.
I will try with Fiddler

Comment: @ToméCerqueira, also take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817548/c-sharp-webclient-and-proxy-server/25331462

Answer (score 0):

Probably a problem with authorization header.
Is the token valid? Does it work with the same token in Postman?

I bet the api can't validate the token and and gives you no authorization to the resources. This is what a 403 would mean (but don't know what the api programmer actually intended by giving you 403).

Do you have access to the api's source code?

The token is really a string "tokentest" and that works with Postman?

Comment: No, the "tokentest" was just an example. I already edited to be similar to what I have

Comment: Did you try it without the proxy, so that you know if the problem is with the api or the proxy server?

Comment: I tried now ant it seems it doesn't work also without the proxy. It's weird because it works in Postman

Comment: try it with the httpclient class

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for xNet.dll instead of webclient Because xNet library are considered best for proxy and webrequest.

```
var request = new HttpRequest()
request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
request.Proxy = Socks5ProxyClient.Parse("10.10.10.10:8080");//can use socks4/5 http
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794346/1169180)

Try adding `User-Agent` in the header

```
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.26.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i did not specify security protocol. Paste this line of code before running any WebClient requests.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

original answer: [How to specify SSL protocol to use for WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491716/how-to-specify-ssl-protocol-to-use-for-webclient-class)